# overwrite inherited value from parent

Tags: html, css

I feel like this is a very silly question. I am trying to have a child element to have a different style from its parent.
As in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vimes1984/j7n3k/4/) example. The id logo should have an orange color. However, it's currently in black because of the style for a. How to overwrite the color and change it to orange?

Thank you

html:

```
<p id="logo"><a href="#">LOGO</a></p>
```

css:

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
}

#logo{
font-family: "Century Gothic";
font-weight: bold;
font-size:2.3em;
color: #FF9D00;
}
```

Comment: Just set a different color for the child element explicitly. Also, the markup in your fiddle seems to be different from the one posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set it more explicitly with `#logo a`, or set the color for the logo as `!important` which will prevent it from being overridden from a higher priority:

```
color: #FF9D00 !important;
```

OR

```
#logo a {
  color: #FF9D00;
}
```